# My options table is huge. What can I do?

Tags: database, options

My options table is 3.2 GB! I ran a query to delete transients (only 172 were there), and I repaired and optimized the table, but it barely made a change. How can I go about finding out what's making this table so huge?

I scanned the site with Wordfence and it came up clean. The site runs super slow, so I assume this table has something to do with that, but I don't know what to look for beyond the transients.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have huge number of rows too? I've e.g. seen a plugin store large sitemaps xml in the options table.

Comment: @birgire, there are 5,193,111 rows. Crazy.

Comment: I guess I would try to briefly scan it (manually or with sql) to find out what kind of options are exploding in numbers.. Then figure out if it's core, theme or plugin related.

Comment: Just tried the plugin "Delete Expired Transients" to see if I missed anything, and it found 2.5 million "obsolete woocommerce sessions from 2.4 and earlier" so I am deleting those now.

Comment: Remember to backup before testing/deleting anything from your db!

Comment: Ultimately that seemed to work. Options table is down to 424 KB now.

Comment: If those transients were not removed, you might want to install a plugin such as cron status checker, because those should be deleted through cron actions.

Comment: just had this issue but with only 1 million... 5 million is alot.  woocommerce should have status -> tools, or transient cleaner plugin works

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread [wp_options is GB in size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346860/wp-options-is-gb-in-size)
My wp_options table dropped from 670GB to 13.5MB after running the optimization commands they outlined

Answer (score 1):

As per the poster, the problem was woocommerce not discarding sessions from the options table after they have expired.

Answer (score 0):

There may be different reasons your DB being too heavy.
Have you being tried with cleaning your DB with 
[wpoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) plugin? 
This might help you!

Comment: I try that, with my 8Mio. entries in the transient database table, but the plugin only deleted about 20 transient entries